# Force use of Integer instead int in method return

Tags: java, wrapper

I have a set of methods that read a property value and return the value in **Integer**, **Float** or **String**.

The problem is next: in case that a developer make this:

```
int value = prop.getValueInteger("id.property");
```

In case that the method don't found the property or have a *NumberFormatException*, I will return null. The assignment fails in this case with NullPointerException. Same to the method Float version (Strings is covered because they don't use primitive with it)

I know that programmers can be forced to catch possible exceptions, but I prefer if there are any options to force the developer to use Integer instead of int.

Comment: No, auto-unboxing is simply a feature of Java as a language. You can't disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent developers just assigning to `int`, when you have a value which might not be present you can return `Optional<Integer>`

```
// never null
Optional<Integer> value = prop.getValueInteger("id.property");
if (value.isPresent()) {
    int v = value.get();
```

You can also value `Optional<Float>` and `Optional<String>` again to make handling of a value which might not be there explicit.

Another option is to never return null, but instead use a default.

```
int value = prop.getValueInteger("id.property", -1);
```

This assumes you can't throw a more useful exception like

```
public int getValueInteger(String name) throws IllegalStateException {
     Object v = getValue(name);
     if (v == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Property " + name + " not set.");
     return convertTo(Integer.class, v);
}
```

Comment: +1 but not such a great difference, just one more hint for the programmer. He still could do `int value = prop.getValueInteger("id.property").get();`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger indeed. I have seen `optional.orElse(null)`  You can bypass it but it will encourage the developer to think about it.

Comment: It's a great respone, anyway I have overloaded versions of the methods with default value. I like the Optional<T> type

Comment: @Genaut you can use `optional.orElse(defaultValue)` to support defaults.